# Unable to print to screen in Python - no error produced

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner python learner. I created this simple program but won't display any error message neither does it work. After the input it stops working. What am I doing wrong? [ Python 3.2]

```
import math

print('''

   |.
   |  .
  a|    . c
   |      .
   |________.
       b

''')

def robot():
    a = float(input('Enter side a, 0 for unknown \n: '))
    b = float(input('Enter side b, 0 for unknown \n: '))
    c = float(input('Enter hypotenuse c, 0 for unknown \n: '))

    if a == 0:
        print = ('a = ', (math.sqrt((c**2)-(b**2))))
    if b == 0:
        print = ('b = ', (math.sqrt((c**2)-(a**2))))
    if c == 0:
        print = ('a = ', (math.sqrt((a**2)+(b**2))))

    input()
    robot()


robot()
```

Thanks

Comment: so the function won't repeat until I click enter

Comment: also you probably should not call robot() inside robot().

Comment: @TimHoffman: it is ok. You need to input ~4000 lines before the stack overflow. Most people will give up before that. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print = ('b = ', (math.sqrt((c**2)-(a**2))))
      ^
```

Delete the assignment operator after the `print`. `print` is a function, so to call it you only have to provide the arguments in the parenthesis, like this:

```
print('b = ', (math.sqrt((c**2)-(a**2))))
```

Comment: @JohnXc Sure thing, happy to be able to help.